# Función para ampliar matriz en R

Tags: r, algoritmos, matrices

Estoy tratando de construir una función que tenga como objetivo ampliar una matriz. Partiendo de esta matriz:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

Si quiero ampliarlo por 2, quiero que salga la siguiente:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    3    3
[2,]    1    1    3    3
[3,]    2    2    4    4
[4,]    2    2    4    4
```

La verdad, todo el código que he creado ha sido excesivamente largo y poco práctico.

Comment: Esta pregunta no termina de quedar clara, le falta información y código, además deberías concretar el problema: de la solución que has hecho, ¿qué es lo que no funciona? ¿con qué errores y dificultades te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

Esta podría ser una forma:

```
grow_matrix <- function(mat, by) {

    d <- dim(mat)
    v <- rep(mat,each=by)
    matrix(unlist(rep(split(rep(mat,each=by), rep(1:d[2], each=d[1]*by)), each=by)), nrow = by*d[1])

}
```

La idea es trabajar la matriz como un vector plano, generar las repeticiones para cada valor y luego reordenarlos de cierta forma. para mantener el orden original cuando volvamos a transformar el vector en una matriz. El parámetro `by` hace referencia a cuanto deseamos hacer crecer cada valor en cada dimensión.

```
m <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)
grow_matrix(m, 2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    3    3
[2,]    1    1    3    3
[3,]    2    2    4    4
[4,]    2    2    4    4
```

No la he probado mucho, pero en teoría, funcionaría también para matrices rectangulares.